# Create custom workflow for office 365 using visual studio and attach the workflow to the lists in the host web

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-workflow

I am using Office 365. I need to create a custom workflow using Visual Studio 2012.  The workflow needs to be triggered whenever any Item in the list in the host web is changed and not in the app web.

The app for SharePoint 2013 project allows you to create Visual Studio 2012 workflow project but there is no option to connect to existing list in the office 365 site.